# setting a static variable in a static class depending on the calling class

Tags: c#

Static class code :

```
static public class CommonValues
{
    public static string _consumerName;
}
```

Assigning from a non-static class :

```
public class CreateSessionConsumer : IClassFixture<CommonFixture>
{              
    private IMockProviderService _mockProviderService;
    private string _mockProviderServiceBaseUri;
    public string _path = "/Security/CreateSession";

    public CreateSessionConsumer(CommonFixture fixture)
    {
        Common.CommonValues._consumerName  = "CreateSessionConsumer";
        Common.CommonValues._providerName = "CreateSessionAPI";        
        _mockProviderService = fixture.MockProviderService;
        _mockProviderService.ClearInteractions(); //NOTE: Clears any previously registered interactions before the test is run
        _mockProviderServiceBaseUri = fixture.MockProviderServiceBaseUri;
        CommonFixture.PactDirectory=@"..\pacts";

        //CommonFixture.Provider=_provider;
    }
}
```

Accessing in this static variable in a generic method:

```
public class CommonFixture : IDisposable
{
    public IPactBuilder PactBuilder { get; private set; }
    public IMockProviderService MockProviderService { get; private set; }

    public int MockServerPort { get { return 9222; } }
    public string MockProviderServiceBaseUri { get { return String.Format("http://localhost:{0}", MockServerPort); } }
    public static string PactDirectory { get; set; }

    public CommonFixture()
    {
        var pactConfig = new PactConfig
        {
            SpecificationVersion = "2.4.6",

            PactDir = @"..\..\..\..\..\pacts",
            LogDir = @".\pact_logs"
        };

        PactBuilder = new PactBuilder(pactConfig);

        PactBuilder.ServiceConsumer(Common.CommonValues._consumerName)
                   .HasPactWith(Common.CommonValues._providerName);

        MockProviderService = PactBuilder.MockService(MockServerPort);
    }
}
```

Issue is, `CreateSessionConsumer` class is not assigning the static variable. And `CommonFixture` is accessing a unassigned variable.

Comment: Could be the order in which the calls are made.

Comment: In this code, the property `get` happens before the property `set`.

Comment: I suspect IClassFixture of XUnit. Will the fixture gets initialized before CreateSessionConsumer() ?

Comment: @DavidG : How can i reverse that?

Comment: For a start, I think having the static variable is a bad idea. I'd probably change it so you initialise the fixture in the `CreateSessionConsumer` class. So in the constructor call `fixture.Initialise("CreateSessionConsumer");`. But it's hard to guess without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: @DavidG : Initialise is a user method?

Comment: Yes, you would need to write it.

Comment: okay, can I get some pseudo code of how it would do that?

Comment: also, can Properties solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could not be handled the way I have asked here. Eventually had to implement Fixture class along with each class file, which sets the consumername and providername individually.